# Error on replace text in header VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I get run-time error 13 (*Type Mismatch*) on my code when I try to run it.
I'm trying to replace a text in a opened Word document through Excel, inside the header.

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(myPath & "\Armaturförteckning.docx")

' Ändrar i Armaturförteckningen
Dim rngStory As Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem as provided by Peter Hewett
  lngJunk = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In WordApp.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      With WordApp.rngStory.Find
        .Text = "ELESTATUS01"
        .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = WordApp.rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
' Stänger dokumentet
WordApp.Documents.Save
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
```

Comment: Which line/instruction is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do a VBA search and replace.  We have a BUNCH of functions that we use, and after many years of refinement, the following is what we use.  It's purely the function that performs a search and replace.

```
Function SimpleSearchAndReplace(SomeDocument As Word.Document, SearchString As String, ReplaceString As String)
With SomeDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = SearchString
    .Replacement.Text = ReplaceString
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems awkward that you have "WordApp.ActiveDocument." when what you probably need is "WordDoc." in your 'lngJunk' and 'For Each' lines.

Comment: I changed my line to:

lngJunk = WordDoc.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType

It throws me an error here
(error 438 object doesn support this property or method)